# Passagem de Parâmetros JavaScript para [Webmethod] C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net, asmx

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para passar parâmetros de uma chamada JavaScript para um Método WebService ASMX sem precisar definir um nome para os parâmetros.

Exemplo:

```
$scope.testar = () =>{
    filtros ={
        id:1,
        funcionalidade:02
    }
    $http.post("minhaUrl/meuMetodo",filtros)
    .success((retorno)=>{
        // 
    })
    .catch((retorno) =>{
        //
    });
}
```

Agora pegar assim no C#

```
[WebMethod]
public void meuMetodo(String[] params){
   int id = params[0];
   int funcionalidade = params[1];

   // 
}
```

Comment: Cara, não sei CSharp, mas... Se você passar um JSON como parâmetro já não resolve teu problema não?

Comment: Cara boa ideia, vou tentar aqui.

Comment: @FelipeSantos eu fiz um exemplo com `Dictionary`, verifique se isso pode ser uma solução ao sua expectativa.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está passando um ***objeto*** que no caso é `filtros` é só especificar no paramento os nomes e seus respectivos tipos que a arquitetura se encarregar de carregar as informações e no exemplo logo abaixo é com framework [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs).

***Exemplo minimo:***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
        CodeBehind="WebFormTest.aspx.cs" 
        Inherits="WebApplication2.WebFormTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            {{quantidade}}
            <button ng-click="btnEnviar()" type="button">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.quantidade = 0;
                $scope.btnEnviar = function () {
                    filtros = {
                        id: 1,
                        funcionalidade: '02'
                    }
                    $http.post("/WebFormTest.aspx/Receive", filtros)
                        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.quantidade = response.data.d;
                            console.log(response);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {

                        });
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebFormTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod()]        
        public static string Receive(string id, string funcionalidade)
        {
            return $"{id} {funcionalidade}";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Se quiser ainda trabalhar com uma classe no [back-end](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_e_back-end) faça o seguinte código, ***exemplo minimo***:

```
public class filtros
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string funcionalidade { get; set; }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            {{quantidade}}
            <button ng-click="btnEnviar()" type="button">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.quantidade = 0;
                $scope.btnEnviar = function () {                    
                    filtros = {
                        'filtros': {
                            id: '1',
                            funcionalidade: '02'
                        }
                    };
                    $http.post("/WebFormTest.aspx/Receive", filtros)
                        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.quantidade = response.data.d;
                            console.log(response);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {

                        });
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
[WebMethod()]        
public static string Receive(filtros filtros)
{
    return $"{filtros.id} { filtros.funcionalidade}";
}
```

---

um outra dica é com um dicionário, exemplo `Dictionary<string, string> filtros`, nesse caso não precisando a inclusão de uma nova classe:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
       CodeBehind="WebFormTest.aspx.cs"
       Inherits="WebApplication2.WebFormTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            {{quantidade}}
            <button ng-click="btnEnviar()" type="button">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.quantidade = 0;
                $scope.btnEnviar = function () {                    
                    filtros = {
                        'filtros': {
                            id: '1',
                            funcionalidade: '02'
                        }
                    };
                    $http.post("/WebFormTest.aspx/Receive", filtros)
                        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.quantidade = response.data.d;
                            console.log(response);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {

                        });
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
[WebMethod()]        
public static string Receive(Dictionary<string, string> filtros)
{
    var v1 = filtros["id"];
    var v2 = filtros["funcionalidade"];
    return $"{v1} {v2}";
}
```

***Referencias***

- [ASP.NET - Criar e Chamar WebMethod em página aspx via jQuery (Ajax)](http://cbsa.com.br/post/aspnet---criar-e-chamar-webmethod-em-pagina-aspx-via-jquery-ajax.aspx)
- [ASP .NET - Chamando um WebMethod via jQuery AJAX - I](http://www.macoratti.net/14/10/aspn_wbjq.htm)
- [How to call webmethod in Asp.net C# - SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110170/how-to-call-webmethod-in-asp-net-c-sharp)
- [Calling webmethod ina aspx.cs file using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688951/calling-webmethod-ina-aspx-cs-file-using-jquery-ajax)
- [Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)
- [Front-end e back-end](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_e_back-end)

Comment: No caso Virgílio, eu não quero especificar os parâmetros no cabeçalho do método no meu backend, quero usar estilo PHP, assim:

request->getParam("id");
request->getParam("funcionalidade");

Comment: @FelipeSantos ele não deserializa arrays dessa forma, deve ter um tipo! PHP é diferente de .NET!

Comment: @Vigilio se eu usar assim public void metodo(String.. params){

}

Comment: @FelipeSantos, o método de um WebService é Static, ele não tem como acessar por `Request.Form`, a maneira de trabalhar com esse cara é as duas formas que eu explifiquei. Outro ponto se agora colocou um código Java, será que é necessário não identificar os paramentros, qual o motivo, se for esses dois por exemplo não vejo o porque? tente explicar os motivos fazendo favor?

Comment: A questão é que eu quero evitar criar classes para passar parâmetros entende? no caso do seu exemplo (filtros filtros) eu teria que criar uma classe chamada Filtros.

Comment: @FelipeSantos eu fiz dois exemplos porque as resposta são feitas para comunidade usufruir de todas as formas, então use a primeira, linguagens fortemente tipadas utilizam tipos para programar! entendeu? e não compare uma linguagem com as outras é errado esse pensamento, cada uma faz ao seu jeito.